# php exec crontab not working

Tags: php, permissions, exec, cron

I trying on my local CentOS 5.3 server, when I try to execute below line in my php code from apache webserver

```
exec("crontab -l", $output, $arg);  
The $arg reply 127  (command not found code)
```

Then I changed below code

```
exec("/usr/bin/crontab -l", $output, $arg); 
The $arg reply 126  (Permission problem code)
```

Here is my current permission of 
/usr/bin/crontab -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 311288 Mar 15  2007 /usr/bin/crontab.
And there is no /etc/cron.allow and /etc/cron.deny file.

I already turned off `Safe_mode` in php.  Any suggestion to solve this problem?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I note that my problem is related to selinux.
It is working, when I disable selinux

echo 0 > /selinux/enforce

But I don't want to disable selinux, is there any option in selinux to allow crontab from apache?

Comment: The apache user does not have the permission to execute crontab.

Comment: is it default setting?  I had install 2 Centos servers before and haven't need to change anything.  It is able to call exec crontab from my php page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add /usr/bin to your shell env path
2. Add crontab to the same group like of the webserver
3. Try in php exec("echo $PATH") to see the path variable. You can also look for unsetenv and temporarly disable it

You can look in the php error log for a detailed description of the error but as you said you are familiar with Linux I can't teach you about user right management. A note to the env variable and the path variable it's not always sure the env variable get exported when you run a program. This is maybe the case with your problem. It means either the os is broken or you have to attach the env variable manually to your program. A workaround can be to look where the shell is looking for programs and symlink the program. In your error log it seems that crontab is in the folder /usr/bin. Also this seems not to be a programming question. Ask at server.stackexchange why crontab isn't found. For example my env looks like this:

LC_PAPER=de_DE
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE
LC_MONETARY=de_DE
AF_PIDDIR=/tmp/af-piddir
UPNP_ROOT=upnpav://
SHELL=/bin/sh
TERM=xterm
DISABLE_GATEWAY=1
GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/hildon/theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
TMPDIR=/var/tmp
MMC_SWAP_LOCATION=/media/mmc1
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE
MMC_MOUNTPOINT=/media/mmc1
OLDPWD=/root
HILDON_FM_OBEX_ROOT=obex://
LAUNCHWRAPPER_NICE_KILL=/etc/osso-af-init/nice-kill-launch-wrapper.sh
INTERNAL_MMC_MOUNTPOINT=/home/user/MyDocs
OSSO_VERSION=RX-51_2009SE_20.2010.36-2_PR_MR0
USER=root
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=00;36:ln=00;35:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;32;00:cd=40;32;00:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;33:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE
SESSION_BUS_PID_FILE=/tmp/dbus_session_bus.pid.user
OSSO_PRODUCT_HARDWARE=RX-51
STATESAVEDIR=/tmp/osso-appl-states
LAUNCHWRAPPER_NICE_TRYRESTART=/etc/osso-af-init/nice-launch-wrapper-tryrestart.sh
OSSO_PRODUCT_FULL_NAME=Nokia N900
OSSO_PRODUCT_RELEASE_FULL_NAME=Maemo 5
OSSO_PRODUCT_RELEASE_NAME=Maemo 5
MYDOCSDIR=/home/user/MyDocs
PATH=/usr/bin/gnu:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
LC_MESSAGES=de_DE
OSSO_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME=Nokia N900
SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS_FILE=/tmp/session_bus_address.user
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE
PWD=/home/user/MyDocs
EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano -w -c
LANG=de_DE
ERR=0
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE
PS1=[\033[1;36m][[\033[0;36m]\u\h[\033[0;37m]:\w[\033[1;36m]][\033[m]$ [\033[0;37;00m]
ILLEGAL_FAT_CHARS=/:*?<>|
OSSO_PRODUCT_KEYBOARD=German
AF_DEFINES_SOURCED=1
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
SDL_AUDIODRIVER=pulse
OSSO_SWAP=/home/user/MyDocs
OSSO_PRODUCT_RELEASE_VERSION=20.2010.36-2
LS_OPTIONS=--color
LAUNCHWRAPPER_TRYRESTART=/etc/osso-af-init/launch-wrapper-tryrestart.sh
OSSO_PRODUCT_NAME=N900
AF_INIT_DIR=/etc/osso-af-init
MMC_DEVICE_FILE=/dev/mmcblk0p1
LOGNAME=root
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-eCbOI2qrVP,guid=cd1dea104334a338a9007b9700000014
LAUNCHWRAPPER=/etc/osso-af-init/launch-wrapper.sh
OSSO_PRODUCT_WLAN_CHANNEL=fcc/us
MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH=255
DISPLAY=:0.0
LAUNCHWRAPPER_NICE=/etc/osso-af-init/nice-launch-wrapper.sh
LC_TIME=de_DE
INTERNAL_MMC_SWAP_LOCATION=/home/user/MyDocs
LC_NAME=de_DE
OSSO_PRODUCT_REGION=Germany
_=/usr/bin/gnu/env

Just type env in the prompt.

Comment: could you tell more detail steps ?

Comment: my webserver is running as apache user.  And below is the  /var/log/httpd/error_log sh: /usr/bin/crontab: Permission denied
sh: crontab: command not found

Comment: I put above script to test.php, the problem only occur when I run from my web browser.  I login with non-root account to ssh via putty, and type command "php test.php", it is successfully exec.

Comment: Try in php exec("echo $PATH") to see the path variable. You can also look for unsetenv and temporarly disable it.

Comment: "/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin" output from  exec('echo $PATH', $output, $arg);

Comment: Then it's probably a user right problem. Just change the group of crontab to be in the same group like the webserver. It wouldn't be necessary to create a new group and I don't know how to do this in the shell either.

Comment: do you mean to change the owner group of /usr/bin/crontab ? e.g. chown root:apache /usr/bin/crontab ?

Comment: No, I mean the group not the owner. You can also set the permission of crontab to execute from other like this chmod g+x /usr/bin/crontab.

Comment: This is current mode of crontab:  crontab -rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 311288 Mar 15 2007 /usr/bin/crontab