# Selinux blocking crontab file changes from PHP

Tags: php, cron, centos, selinux

I'm using PHP 7 on CentoOS 7 system. The following line

```
              exec('echo "'.$some_cron_content.'" | crontab -');
```

edits crotab file named `apache` that is located in `/var/spool/cron/apache` for **`apache`** user.

If I set **`setenforce 0`** everything works fine. But when the selinux is enabled crontab file does not change.

`apache` file has the following permissions (when I run `ls -lZ /var/spool/cron/apache`)

```
    -rw----rwx. apache apache system_u:object_r:shadow_t:s0    /var/spool/cron/apache
```

what permissions should I set for the `apache` file to solve that problem?

Comment: If you have policycoreutils installed, audit2allow and audit2why will be of help,

Comment: `audit2allow -i /var/log/audit/audit.log` this command gives me `This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'httpd_execmem'
allow httpd_t self:process execmem;
allow httpd_t shadow_t:file open;`

Comment: This is a dupe of a 9 (!) year old still-unanswered question: [php exec crontab not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884450/php-exec-crontab-not-working) - same issue, SELinux preventing Apache from executing `crontab`.  Would be nice to get a good answer for this question.

Comment: Also, 3y 9m ago: [Selinux blocks the crontab command from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984667/selinux-blocks-the-crontab-command-from-php)